# How to convert array in json format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to send `ids`(as array) in json format for that I used `JSON.stringify(ids);` and stored in variable `z` I am using array at server side to get values.

```
var ids = $("#infolist li div.No").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
alert(ids);
console.log(ids);
if (ids) {
    var z = JSON.stringify(ids);
    alert(z);
    $.ajax({
        url: "UpdateNotification",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {ids: z},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(z);
            alert("success " + data.st);
        }
    });
}
```

`console.log(ids)` is showing `["25","27","28"]`.
`console.log(z)` is showing `["25","27","28"]`.

My problem is it is not calling server side method.
I may be due to not proper json format of data.
How to make it correct?

**EDIT**

At url If I use directly

http://localhost:8084/tt/UpdateNotification?ids=%5B%2225%22%2C%2227%22%2C%2228%22%5D

No server side method is called. This is the output of JSON.stratefy(ids).

But If I use below

http://localhost:8084/tt/UpdateNotification?ids=%2225%22&ids=%2226%22&ids=%2227%22

This calles ther serverside method

Comment: Arrays are correct JSON formats.  There is no need to do `{ids: z}` unless you're going to be sending other data in that object.  You can simply do `z`

Comment: are you ser the URL is correct:  url: "UpdateNotification",

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem here.  Is your server supposed the manipulate the data, and it's supposed to show the changed data server-side?

Comment: show your server side code! are there any console errors?

Comment: Please see the question update

Comment: @xrcwrn Your update shows that your server isn't expecting JSON at all, but standard querystring parameters

Comment: @GuruprasadRao at server side I used `System.out.println("ID ARE " + getIds().length);
            for (String a : getIds()) {
                System.out.print(" "+a);
            }`

Comment: @RGraham  ok  means there should also some json plugin?\

Comment: @xrcwrn You should post another question with your Java code and ask why your method isn't being hit. This may be related to how your sending the data, but it would be better answered by a Java developer.

Comment: @RGraham Have I generated the correct json using `JSON.stringify(ids);`

Comment: @RGraham I solved my problem I was unable to identify where is problem

Answer (score 0):

No need for `var z = JSON.stringify(ids);`.

Just do:

```
// ...

data: { ids: ids },

// ...
```

Comment: It is showing `http://localhost:8084/tt/UpdateNotification?ids%5B%5D=25&ids%5B%5D=27&ids%5B%5D=28` can we remove %5B%5D` after removing it this is working perfectly

Comment: Remove `dataType` and `data`, and just have: `url: "UpdateNotification/?ids=" + encodeURIComponent(ids),`